# Validation rule Not working properly

Tags: validation, validation-rule, date

My validation rule, I am playing around. Should activate only when June 15/2018 or June 16 2018.  But it activates for any date.  Not sure why.

```
OR(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "1 - Prospect"), 
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "2 - Strategy/Proposal Generation"), 
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "3 - Proposal Submitted"), 
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "4 - Negotiation") ) && 
OR(RecordTypeId ="008xzZ",RecordTypeId ="001ZUOX") && OR( 
DATE( YEAR(CloseDate),MONTH(CloseDate),DAY(CloseDate)) <> DATE(2018,6,15), 
DATE( YEAR(CloseDate),MONTH(CloseDate),DAY(CloseDate)) <> DATE(2018,6,16))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation rules go off if they evaluate to `true`. The salient portion of your formula:

```
OR( 
   DATE(YEAR(CloseDate),MONTH(CloseDate),DAY(CloseDate)) <> DATE(2018,6,15), 
   DATE(YEAR(CloseDate),MONTH(CloseDate),DAY(CloseDate)) <> DATE(2018,6,16)
)
```

will evaluate to `true` for any date *other than* 2018-06-15 and 2018-06-16. You need to simply invert the logic by changing `<>` to `=`. (Also, `CloseDate` is already a Date value).

As an aside, formulas become incredibly hard to read when you mix `&&` operator style and `OR()` function-style logic. Sticking with one style and using indentation to show the level of nesting helps make the formula more readable.

Comment: Spot on, and don't forget to use references for those recordtype names instead of hard-coding the IDs.

Comment: Can i use CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3) to get march, june, september, december?

Comment: I don't really follow, @nameishi, but that sounds like a separate question.